# How to get MSP subproject statusdate in a masterplan from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I am building an Excel dashboard which I want it to get data from my department MSP Masterplan.

So far I managed to get all data I want except the statusdate of subprojects.

```
Sub ImportMSPData()

Dim r As Range
Dim MSP As MSProject.Application
Dim proj As Project
Dim subproj As Subproject
Dim ligne As Long

Set MSP = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
MSP.Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

AppActivate MSP
If MSP.FileOpenEx(MasterplanPath, , , , , , , , , , , pjDoNotOpenPool) Then
    Set proj = MSP.ActiveProject
Else
    MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & Files.MspRoutine
    Exit Sub
End If

ligne = 1

For Each subproj In proj.Subprojects
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 1).Value = subproj.Path
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 2).Value = Left(subproj.InsertedProjectSummary.Name, 15)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 3).Value = Mid(subproj.InsertedProjectSummary.Name, 19)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 5).Value = subproj.InsertedProjectSummary.Start
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 6).Value = subproj.InsertedProjectSummary.Finish
        ligne = ligne + 1
Next
End Sub
```

I can get Statusdate by looping through all supbrojects, opening them, reading data and closing after that, but it takes forever depending on the number of subprojects. Is there a way I can get this information in the loop here above without opening the subprojects?

Comment: Would the date when the subproject's file last was modified suffice, or do you want the date entered into a cell in the spreadsheet?

Comment: I really want to get the status date from each subprojects to copy them in an excel worksheet with other datas, so that I can make a graph out of these dates to make a KPI on percentage of planning updates. Date of file modified isn't relevant as it can have been opened and modified but not updated

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that for each read/write operation on a cell in excel you consume memory, and with that speed. For optimalisation instead of writing every value directly to a cell you could write them to an array, and later write the array to your worksheet.

Comment: Yes, I can do that of course, but honestly, the time gained by doing so would be minimal. Opening, reading and closing each subproject is what is really time-consuming in this operation, which is why I really want to get rid of that.
Actual macro I posted above runs almost instantaneously

Comment: There are python packages which can read Excel-files and do operations on them without actually opening them in Excel. Would this be an option for you, or are you bound to using vba? I think it may be possible to do what you want using queries in VBA, but I have no real idea of how you'd actually go about implementing this.

Comment: Actually I want to read MSP data from Excel VBA. And I know nothing about Python but maybe it could help, I have no idea

Comment: Since you've discovered reading from sub-projects (a pull operation) is slow, perhaps you could make use of each sub-project's `Project_BeforeSave` event and push their status data somewhere?

Comment: Nice tip @Jerred but it implies people actually work in their schedule to do so, which is not the case at the moment. But most certainly I will implement that option afterwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Status Date for the SubProjects, use the [SourceProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.subproject.sourceproject) property to reference the underlying subproject properties:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(ligne, 7).Value = subproj.SourceProject.StatusDate
```

Comment: Thanks @Rachel, I was sure you would have the answer :-) The MSDN description wasn't clear enough that's why I didn't try the `SourceProject` property. It does what I was looking for but is as slow as looping through all subprojects. Guess there is no other way to speed up process.

Comment: Agreed--to get an project-level information from the subprojects, they need to be opened in memory.